# What is Visual Studio GDR R2, and do I still need the Power Tools?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, gdr

I am working on quite a large DB based project and I like the look of a few of the [power tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=73BA5038-8E37-4C8E-812B-DB14EDE2C354&displaylang=en).

Looking through the related downloads, I found out about [GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en), I cannot find out that much information about it - Not even sure what GDR stands for, but one thing that caught my eye -

"this release incorporates **many** previously released Power Tools as well as several new features"

It also says under the install section -

"**Uninstall** the Database Edition Power Tools if installed."

So,

1. Does it contain ***all*** of them and a few extra features, or ***only*** a few?
2. What does GDR stand for!?
3. Is it worth using it over the standard power tools?

## Edit -

Paul Baker's answer is great and has answered 2, along with giving me a lot of information, but I am still unclear on points 1 and 2. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GDR = General Distribution Release.
You may find [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483214.aspx) helpful.

Comment: I will mark as answer if no one else responds, but I would still like to know if this includes all the powertoys or just some as I still find this very unclear.

Comment: I still haven't got an answer from anyone about the power tools, but I guess this will have to do! Thanks for your help.